# Error: Cannot read property of undefiended

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I'm trying to make a simple conversion with [color.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js) from [this library](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker), and I can't seem to do it. I tried dong the following:

```
var myColor = new Colors();

var hslColor = myColor.colorConverter.hsv2hsl({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
});
```

But I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hsv2hsl' of undefined

Why am I getting the error, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

**Code Snippet**

```js
var myColor = new Colors();

var hslColor = myColor.colorConverter.hsv2hsl({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
});
console.log(hslColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dig in a little bit and found the right way

```
var myColor = new Colors();
var hslColor = myColor.convertColor({
  h: 100,
  s: 100,
  v: 100
},'hsv2hsl')
```

Comment: When I do that, I get weird results. The result of the above code snippet is: `h: 100, s: -1.0204081632653061, l: -4900`   https://jsfiddle.net/3eavjrgL/1/

Comment: i took the convert function from **colors.js** and test it and got the same result, so the problem is in the colors.js **[check here]**(https://jsfiddle.net/puemos/q9at4kLq/)

Comment: convertColor is case sensitive: hsv means components from 0 to 1 whereas HSV means H: 0 - 360, S: 0 - 100, V: 0 - 100. So you probably wanted to convert from HSV2HSL not from hsv2hsl (You can also use hsv2HSL or HSV2hsl)

Answer (score 5):

An instance of `Colors` [doesn't have a `colorConverter` property.](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker#the-color-model-the-methods-and-more)

Comment: I was right about to post the same answer -- `ColorConverter` looks to be a private utility within the closure, and isn't accessible directly by anything trying to use `Colors`

Comment: See @Shy A's answer. It most definitely does!

Answer (score 0):

`myColor.colorConverter` doesn't exist. The right way is to use `myColor`'s method `convertColor()`. The second argument of `convertColor()` is case sensitive:

```
var myColor = new Colors();
var hslColor = myColor.convertColor({
    h: 100,
    s: 100,
    v: 100
},'HSV2HSL'); // not 'hsv2hsl'
```

`hsv` means components from 0 to 1 whereas `HSV` means H: 0 - 360, S: 0 - 100, V: 0 - 100. So you probably want to convert from `HSV2HSL` not from `hsv2hsl`

You can also mix it like `hsv2HSL` or `HSV2hsl`.